# WAS and IHS 8.5.5.x on two different OS levels?

Tags: oracle, websphere, version, httpserver

We're trying to migrate an existing WAS-IHS-WEBGATE-OAM10G from solaris box to linux servers., my questions is are there any dependencies or issues with having WAS/IHS on two different OS Version levels?? and does WEBGATE 10G & 11g supports IHS 8.5.5.X on Linux version 6.x and 7.x??

Answer (score 2):

There is no dependency between the OS/platform/architecture of IHS and that of WebSphere. They can be run on separate OS'es or OS versions -- they communicate via HTTP only.

WebGate has ample doc about IHS and RHEL6/RHEL7 would be extremely pervasive, but I don't think double-checking some product support matrix fits the Q&A format of stackoverflow.